# PLSQL. I have 3 stored procedure and they are inserting/filling in different Oracle Db tables. I want them running in parallel order...Any ideas?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have 3 stored procedure ,1 master stored procedure and 1 end stored procedure.

I want OneSP,TwoSP and ThreeSP all running in same time(parallel), and endStoredProcedure will only run until ONE,TWO,THREE completed.

This Master stored Procedure will be trigger by third party software so I do not want them running on some special time.

I know it is a silly question, but please help me guys, much appreciate!

```
create or replace Procedure MasterStoredProcedure as

BEGIN
     OneSP;--     These three SP insert data into three different tables and running in parallel .

     TwoSP;--    These three SP insert data into three different tables and running in parallel .

     ThreeSP;--    These three SP insert data into three different tables and running in parallel .


     endStoredProcedure;   --this SP will only run until ONE, TWO, Three all complete


END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In normal execution, it is not possible to achieve the parallel execution of the procedure.

But, there is a way to achieve it using the `DBMS_JOB` package. It will execute the procedures given to the Job in background and we will get notified once it is completed using `DBMS_ALERT.SIGNAL` and `DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE` method:

> ```
> DECLARE
>     LV_JOB_NO   NUMBER;
>     MESSAGE1    VARCHAR2(50);
>     MESSAGE2    VARCHAR2(50);
>     MESSAGE3    VARCHAR2(50);
>     STATUS1     NUMBER;
>     STATUS2     NUMBER;
>     STATUS3     NUMBER;
> BEGIN
>     --REGISTERING 3 PROCESSES FOR THREE DIFFERENT PROCEDURES
>     DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER('PROCESS1');
>     DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER('PROCESS2');
>     DBMS_ALERT.REGISTER('PROCESS3');
>     -- SUBMITTING THE PROCEDURES FOR EXECUTION
>     -- IT WILL BE EXECUTED IN THE BACKGROUND
>     DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(LV_JOB_NO, 'OneSP; DBMS_ALERT.SIGNAL(''PROCESS1'',''COMPLETED''); COMMIT;');
>     DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(LV_JOB_NO, 'TwoSP; DBMS_ALERT.SIGNAL(''PROCESS2'',''COMPLETED''); COMMIT;');
>     DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(LV_JOB_NO, 'ThreeSP; DBMS_ALERT.SIGNAL(''PROCESS3'',''COMPLETED''); COMMIT;');
>     -- WAITING FOR THE BACKGROUND PROCESS TO COMPLETE AND FETCHING THE SIGNAL OF COMPLETED FROM THEM
>     DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE('PROCESS1', MESSAGE1, STATUS1);
>     DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE('PROCESS2', MESSAGE2, STATUS2);
>     DBMS_ALERT.WAITONE('PROCESS3', MESSAGE2, STATUS3);
>     -- IF ALL THE PROCEDURES ARE COMPLETED THEN ONLY EXECUTE THE ENDSTOREDPROCEDURE
>     IF STATUS1 = 0 AND STATUS2 = 0 AND STATUS3 = 0 THEN
>         ENDSTOREDPROCEDURE;
>     END IF;
> END;
> /
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: shouldn't that be 'PROCESS1' etc rather than 'P1'?

Comment: @Tejash. I do the code as you post up there. The Stored procedure going to a Dead Loop.